# failed to reinstall apache2 and php

Tags: server, apache2, php

I'm a newbie and I messed up with a server trying to reinstall apache2 and php, I did extensive searches inside this forum and in the interwebs but no solution for similar problems helped me.
At the moment my web server downloads files instead of opening the web pages so i'm trying to clean up my php installation, I think I messed up my package list or php installation.

apt-get install php5

```
    # apt-get install php5Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25) but it is not going to be installed or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: php5-common (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25) but it is not going to be installed
 php5.6-fpm : Depends: php5.6-common (= 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.6.26-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

apt-get install php

```
# apt-get install phpReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php : Depends: php7.0 but it is not going to be installed
 php5.6-fpm : Depends: php5.6-common (= 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.6.26-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

apt-get -f install

```
# apt-get -f installReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  php5.6-fpm
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php5.6-fpm
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1569 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5.6-fpm:
 php5.6-fpm depends on php5.6-common (= 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5.6-common on system is 5.6.26-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5.6-fpm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                       Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5.6-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

any help will be appreciated.

SOLUTION:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends php5.6*
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install php php5.6
```

looks like the problem is solved, I'm not 100% sure because my web server still doesn't interpret php but I'm not getting those pesky installation errors anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal and type

```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it doesn't help then do this

```
  sudo apt autoremove <packagename>
```

If this doesn't help then you
Need an internet connection.Type in terminal

```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!

UPDATE :

```
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends   *put here all the things which are listed in ur Depends: *
  sudo apt-get install -f
```

Update 2:
Create a dummy initscript to fool dpkg:(use nano/gedit/vim)

```
 sudo nano /etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm
```

Enter the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash
  exit 0
```

Save the file, set execution permission (`sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm`) and try to `sudo apt-get remove php5.6-fpm` again.
Dot this for all packages.

Comment: sadly i don't have software-properties-gtk and can't apt-get install it because i get that same error, also i'm connecting via ssh

Comment: 'Did u try sudo apt install --reinstall package

Comment: # apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-gtk

Comment: Nahh..not software properties..put the packages which are giving errors... like put apache2 php... Whichever u were installing

Comment: same error:  E: Unable to locate package php5. Probably because i removed source.list ?

Comment: # apt-get install --reinstall php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php : Depends: php7.0 but it is not going to be installed
 php5.6-fpm : Depends: php5.6-common (= 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.6.26-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Yaa it is because there is no source.list file to fetch from...get a new fresh sources.list file for your ubuntu version on google if possible...and put it into the folder from where u removed it.....can also try by booting live session of ubuntu(your version only) and copy sources.list..use sudo everywhere

Comment: I've placed a new source.list but still getting those errors

Comment: now first run sudo apt-get update and then reinstall command

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Is ur ubuntu version 15.04?

Comment: 12.04.5 LTS precise

Comment: sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 php5 whichever u installed

Comment: # sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 php php5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php is not installed, so not removed
Package php5.6 is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5.6-fpm : Depends: php5.6-common (= 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.6.26-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: `sudo dpkg --remove package-name`put php5 ..try with Apache too

Comment: I think this is the main error # sudo dpkg --remove php*
(Reading database ... 68754 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5.6-cli ...
Removing php5.6-fpm ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm not found.
dpkg: error processing php5.6-fpm (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100Removing php5.6-opcache ...
Removing php5.6-json ...
Removing php5.6-readline ...
Removing php5.6-common ...
Removing php-common ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5.6-fpm

Comment: Check update part in answer

Comment: not sure if i'm doing right but i get this: # sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends php5.6-fpm
(Reading database ... 68647 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5.6-fpm ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm not found.
dpkg: error processing php5.6-fpm (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5.6-fpm

Comment: Checkout update 2:.. seems like dpkg doesn't want to listen

Comment: Does it work!?..let me know

Comment: Yeah it worked, thank you a lot! I owe you a beer ;)

Comment: Haha... glad i could help...you are welcome:)